# Difficulty in finding elements in selenium using xpath

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am finding difficulty in identifying search button in selenium.
The issue is the same when i am using xpath.
My action would be to click on SearchButton
Here is the snippet of HTML code.

[image: Attached HTML Code]
I am trying to identify element using below xpath

```
WebElement search=new WebDriverWait(driver,15)
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
      By.xpath("//p[@class='btnRow']/name[@name='SearchButton']")));
```

Kindly help me in this regard as i am not able to proceed

Comment: Why you are not using id instead of xpath ? and you can try with xpath .//p[@class='btnRow' and @name='SearchButton']

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath searches for an element `name` but it is an `input`. Try the following instead:

```
WebElement search=new WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//p[@class='btnRow']/input[@name='SearchButton']")));
```

Comment: It is still not searchable
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == /p[@class='btnRow' and @name='SearchButton']
If we see the HTML div class is referring IFrameContent.
Is there any other way to access the button

Comment: The xpath you used according to the error message is not the one from my answer.

Comment: Hello Andreas,
Same thing
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //p[@class='btnRow']/input[@name='SearchButton']

Comment: According to your screenshot of the html code the xpath in the answer is correct. See here: [http://xpathfiddle.net/1WWQBN](http://xpathfiddle.net/1WWQBN)

Comment: You can see
onmousedown=javascript:Hide() in html code
Is that the problem

Answer (score 0):

Class is usually not unique. You must understand what are unique properties in the html code that you can use to select the element. ID is usually unique, therefore people commonly search by id.

Please give this a try:

```
by.Xpath("//div[@id='maincontent']//input[@id='SearchButton']")
```

In case, if you still can't find the element, try separating the xpath and debug if you get the element that you wanted. Including the Xpath from @Andreas Scheibleger which looks fine to me too.